# Ignoring a previous value

Tags: pine-script

I want to plot a series of values from highest to lowest (array.sort doesn't give me what I want). When I try to plot the 2nd highest value it returns to 0. I basically just want to plot the 1st highest, then 2nd, then 3rd etc.

```
study("My Script")

a= 11
b= 2
c= 7
d = 15

e = max(a,b,c,d)
f = max(a,b,c,d) - e

plot(e, style=plot.style_columns, show_last=1, offset=0)
plot(f, style=plot.style_columns, show_last=1, offset=-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use this?

```
//@version=4
study("")

a = 11
b = 2
c = 7
d = 15

f_secondHighest(_v1, _v2, _v3, _v4) =>
    float[] _v = array.new_float()
    array.push(_v, _v1)
    array.push(_v, _v2)
    array.push(_v, _v3)
    array.push(_v, _v4)
    array.sort(_v, order.descending)
    array.get(_v, 1)

plot(f_secondHighest(a,b,c,d))
```

Comment: Yes! thank you. I don't quite understand arrays yet.  2 follow up questions.  do I have to use that code for every plot or can I just do 

plot(array.get(_v,0))
plot(array.get(_v,1))
plot(array.get(_v,2))

Whenever I do that it says undeclared identifier _v

Second question: how would I get 'a' to plot above its corresponding column, even as the value changes? would it be be plotshape(f_secondHighest(a,b,c,d), text = tostring(f_secondHighest(a,b,c,d)).  Thank you

Comment: You need to repeat the last line if you want to plot the result for other sets of values.